# installing React bootstrap react in react. Object not found,

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have installed a react app and react bootstrap. This is running in a wordpress theme. I have spent all day trying to resolve this issue with no luck.

i keep getting:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
useUncontrolledProp 


 var wasPropRef = useRef(propValue !== undefined);
```

im currently these 'dependencies' using in package json :

```
    "react": "16.7.0-alpha.2",
    "react-dom": "16.7.0-alpha.2",
    "react-router-dom": "4.4.0-beta.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. "react-bootstrap" is not presented in your dependencies, so may be you have not installed it.
2. From some variable you want to call function but it is object. So it is like to call:

   ```
   let object = new Object();
    object(); // throws TypeError: object is not a function
   ```
3. If you post more code it is possible to better understand problem.